# What's the difference between "super()" and "super(props)" in React when using es6 classes?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

When is it important to pass `props` to `super()`, and why?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(); // or super(props) ?
  }
}
```

Comment: A good explanation can also be found at https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/

Answer (score 838, accepted):

There is only one reason when one needs to pass `props` to `super()`:

**When you want to access `this.props` in constructor.**

Passing:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        console.log(this.props)
        // -> { icon: 'home', … }
    }
}
```

Not passing:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {    
    constructor(props) {
        super()

        console.log(this.props)
        // -> undefined

        // Props parameter is still available
        console.log(props)
        // -> { icon: 'home', … }
    }

    render() {
        // No difference outside constructor
        console.log(this.props)
        // -> { icon: 'home', … }
    }
}
```

Note that passing or not passing `props` to `super` has **no effect** on later uses of `this.props` outside `constructor`. That is `render`, `shouldComponentUpdate`, or event handlers **always** have access to it.

This is explicitly said in one Sophie Alpert's [answer](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/should-we-include-the-props-parameter-to-class-constructors-when-declaring-components-using-es6-classes/2781/2) to a similar question.

---

The documentation—[State and Lifecycle, Adding Local State to a Class, point 2](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class)—recommends:

> Class components should always call the base constructor with `props`.

However, no reason is provided. We can speculate it is either because of subclassing or for future compatibility.

(Thanks @MattBrowne for the link)

Comment: I think you are correct, despite the other answers getting more votes. `this.props` is `undefined` unless passed to `super()`. Either way, it does not affect later rendering or availability of `this.props` in the `render()` function.

Comment: I find the answer confusing, because if I pass `props` to super I get access to `this.props` not only in the `constructor() but in the entire class. I don't find it redundand at all.

Comment: @Rotareti, no, actually rest of the class does not depend on this construct, that is the point. Component receives props by a different way that by constructor parameter. And since you pass initial props to `super`, you have reference to them in the constructor.

Comment: I have made a pen which shows this: http://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/PGZApy/

Comment: According to the React documentation, you should always pass `props` to `super()`: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class. I'm not sure why, since as you point out `this.props` is accessible in other methods either way...perhaps they're recommending this for future compatibility in case future versions of React might want to do something with `props` in the constructor?

Comment: @MattBrowne, good catch! I believe that is because you can subclass components and create a chain of inherited components. Then class higher would not know about those props. However, that is just a speculation.

Comment: I think, "*When you want to access this.props in constructor,*" confused me a little, esp when followed by, "*Which is prob redundant since you already have a reference to it.*" There, "it" === the *content* within `props` elsewhere, not literally the `this.props` named reference. That is, ***as a side effect*** of including the named arg in your `super` call, you will *also* have `this.props` throughout the constructor, though the constructor's named argument makes that side effect redundant. Though, as @MattBrowne says, passing the arg to super is precisely what you *should* do. Sound right?

Comment: @ruffin, I am not sure I understand what you found confusing. I decided to add code examples which I believe will help. Do you still find it confusing?

At the bottom of the answer, I discuss what the docs recommend. Should that part be also updated?

Comment: Your code examples precisely address what confused me the first time. If I could upvote again, I would. ;^) Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm just opening a can of worms here, but **why _ever_ pass `props` to `super` when, as you pointed out, the `props` parameter is right there available for us to use within the constructor**, and `this.props` works everywhere else?

Is there a benefit at all to using `this.props` over just `props`? Is it bad practice to destructure off of `props` in the constructor?

I think I'm still failing to see a case when you'd ever need to pass `props` to `super`, but I'm willing to bet it's just my ignorance, ha.

Comment: @indiesquidge, there is no known reason why to do that. It is just recommended in the docs and it might help you in the future, or not. I'd say it's safe to omit it now.

Comment: @indiesquidge - I'm also failing to see strong reasoning in using `super()` vs `super(props)` in a React component based on the current discussion of this thread. However, my thought is that `this.props` is the standard use case when a component is mounted, and therefore using `props` is inconsistent and may lead to subtle bugs. For example, someone could write a script that parses `this.props` instead of `props` from a constructor's source code, and not really think twice that `props` is allowed as well.

Comment: If you use `super(props)`, you can call methods that use `this.props` *in from constructor*, like `this.doStuffUsingThisDotProps()`, without having to pass on the props parameter to those methods/functions. I just wrote a constructor doing this, which seemingly would require me to use `super(props)` first, according to the answers to this question.

Comment: This might be compatibility issue or "future thinking" of react. At strongly typed languages such as C# or Java, you will have to pass constructor parameters to base class if it is enforced by abstract/base class. So, if react developers are seeking JavaScript becoming with more strongly typed with ES6 standards and TypeScript, it might be told it is a good practice to pass it through.

Comment: They suggest to call base constructor with props on their documentation, but I found a thread which not strongly suggesting about that: https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/should-we-include-the-props-parameter-to-class-constructors-when-declaring-components-using-es6-classes/2781

Comment: @Bayu, thanks for the link. I mention this thread in the answer already ;)

Comment: @RobinPokorny, oh... yeah, you are right :). I got those link from another googling activity, but was not click on yours ( because I didn't know if Sophie Alpert is official React team ) LOL. It strange the person in React team speak differently with their documentation.

Comment: The other link says that : 
"According to Ben Alpert with the React team it's only necessary to pass props into the constructor if you intend on using this.props inside the constructor. After the constructor is invoked, React attaches the props to the component from the outside."

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835371/is-the-call-to-superprops-in-an-es6-class-important

Comment: @peevesy, what do you mean? That is exactly what I link in the answer.

Answer (score 75):

In this example, you are extending the `React.Component` class, and per the ES2015 spec, a child class constructor cannot make use of `this` until `super()` has been called; also, ES2015 class constructors have to call `super()` if they are subclasses.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this); // Reference Error
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}
```

By contrast:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log(this); // this logged to console
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}
```

More detail as per [this excellent stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31079103)

You may see examples of components created by extending the `React.Component` class that do not call `super()` but you'll notice these don't have a `constructor`, hence why it is not necessary.

```
class MyOtherComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hi {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}
```

One point of confusion I've seen from some developers I've spoken to is that the components that have no `constructor` and therefore do not call `super()` anywhere, still have `this.props` available in the `render()` method. Remember that this rule and this need to create a `this` binding for the `constructor` only applies to the `constructor`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but it doesn't answer my original question (difference between `super()` and `super(props)`).

Answer (score 67):

When you pass `props` to `super`, the props get assigned to `this`. Take a look at the following scenario:

```
constructor(props) {
    super();
    console.log(this.props) //undefined
}
```

How ever when you do :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props) //props will get logged.
}
```

Comment: This answer is half correct, This example is only for the constructor method. For example, even if you don't write super(props), this.props under the render method will still be assigned and available.
The only reason mentioned above is when using this.props in the constructor.

Answer (score 24):

When implementing the `constructor()` function inside a React component, `super()` is a requirement. Keep in mind that your `MyComponent` component is extending or borrowing functionality from the `React.Component` base class.

This base class has a `constructor()` function of its own that has some code inside of it, to setup our React component for us.

When we define a `constructor()` function inside our `MyComponent` class, we are essentially, overriding or replacing the `constructor()` function that is inside the `React.Component` class, but we still need to ensure that all the setup code inside of this `constructor()` function still gets called.

So to ensure that the `React.Component`’s `constructor()` function gets called, we call `super(props)`. `super(props)` is a reference to the parents `constructor()` function, that’s all it is.

We have to add `super(props)` every single time we define a `constructor()` function inside a class-based component.

If we don’t we will see an error saying that we have to call `super(props)`.

The entire reason for defining this `constructor()` funciton is to initialize our state object.

So in order to initialize our state object, underneath the super call I am going to write:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {};
   }

  // React says we have to define render()
  render() {
    return <div>Hello world</div>;
  }
};
```

So we have defined our `constructor()` method, initialized our state object by creating a JavaScript object, assigning a property or key/value pair to it, assigning the result of that to `this.state`. Now of course this is just an example here so I have not really assigned a key/value pair to the state object, its just an empty object.

Answer (score 22):

Dan Abramov wrote an article on this topic:

[Why Do We Write super(props)?](https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/)

And the gist of it is that it's helpful to have a habit of *passing* it to avoid this scenario, that honestly, I don't see it unlikely to happen:

```
// Inside React
class Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.props = props;
    // ...
  }
}

// Inside your code
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(); //  We forgot to pass props
    console.log(props);      // ✅ {}
    console.log(this.props); //  undefined 
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 17):

As per [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/52752446760dee0bc7232b4146f5a309ac57f065/src/isomorphic/modern/class/ReactComponent.js#L23)

```
function ReactComponent(props, context) {
  this.props = props;
  this.context = context;
}
```

you must pass `props` every time you have props and you don't put them into `this.props` manually.

Comment: I'm still not clear on this. if you look at [these](https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/components/Explore.js) two [components](https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/components/List.js), you can see one calls `super(props)` and the other doesn't. But their consumers both set props. What is the difference?

Comment: Does this mean that `this.props = props` and `super(props)` are the same thing?

Comment: This is not true. [ReactElement](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/3b96650e39ddda5ba49245713ef16dbc52d25e9e/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElement.js#L52) actually sets `this.props` from the ‘outside’–irrespective of what is done in the constructor.

Answer (score 13):

`super()` is used to call the parent constructor.

`super(props)` would pass `props` to the parent constructor.

From your example, `super(props)` would call the `React.Component` constructor passing in `props` as the argument.

More information on `super`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Comment: Yes, that's what it does. But *why*? And *when* is one of the two forms required in React?

Answer (score 6):

For react version 16.6.3, we use *super(props)* to initialize state element ***name : this.props.name***

```js
constructor(props){
    super(props);        
}
state = {
  name:this.props.name 
    //otherwise not defined
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the fiddle I've made:[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/beshanoe/zpxbLw4j/1/.). It shows that props are assigned not in the constructor by default. As I understand they are assinged in the method `React.createElement`. Hence `super(props)` should be called only when the superclass's constructor manually assings `props` to `this.props`. If you just extend the `React.Component` calling `super(props)` will do nothing with props. Maybe It will be changed in the next versions of React.

Answer (score 5):

Here we won't get this in the constructor so it will return undefined, but we will be able to fetch this outside the constructor function

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this); // Reference Error i.e return undefined
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}
```

If we are using super(), then we can fetch the "this" variable inside the constructor as well

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log(this); // this logged to console
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}
```

**So when we are using super(); we will be able to fetch this but this.props will be undefined in the constructor. But other than constructor, this.props will not return undefined.**

**If we use super(props), then we can use this.props value inside the constructor as well**

**[Sophie Alpert's Answer](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/should-we-include-the-props-parameter-to-class-constructors-when-declaring-components-using-es6-classes/2781/2)**

> If you want to use this.props in the constructor, you need to pass
>   props to super. Otherwise, it doesn’t matter because React sets .props
>   on the instance from the outside immediately after calling the
>   constructor.