# "Uncaught ReferenceError: this is not defined" in class constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am playing with the new stuff in JavaScript/ES6. I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: this is not defined(...) player.js:5` in my code. As far as I see, there are no errors here! Is this a bug? Any workarounds?

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/entity.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/player.js"></script>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="screen" width=500 height=500></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">initialize();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

entity.js

```
"use strict";

class Entity {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Entity");
    }
}
```

player.js

```
"use strict";

class Player extends Entity {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Created"); // <- error here
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something or did you never declare `initialize` anywhere???

Comment: It was old and irrelevant code that was left in my mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript ES6 class extend without super](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31067368/javascript-es6-class-extend-without-super)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is a fact of the new class syntax. Your subclass needs to call `super()` in order for the class to be properly initialized, e.g.

```
super(arg1, arg2, argN);
```

with whatever arguments the parent constructor needs.

It is required that, if execution reaches the end of a `constructor` function, the value of `this` needs to have been initialized to something. You either need to be in a base class (where `this` is auto-initialized), have called `super()` so `this` is initialized, or `return`ed an alternative object.

```
class Player extends Entity {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("Created"); ;// error here
  }
}
```

You can think of it like `constructor` functions kind of have an automatic `return this` at the end of them.