# Circular dependency Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, circular-dependency

We have circular depenency structure that should be fine logically. Light imports Node which imports NodeManager which inturn imports Light. When running our code we get the following

```
"Super expression must either be null or a function"
```

NodeManager

```
// in NodeManager.js
import Light from '../../Light.js'

class NodeManager {
  static _instance;
  static getInstance() {
    if(NodeManager._instance === undefined) {
      NodeManager._instance = new NodeManager();
    }
   return NodeManager._instance;
  }
  ...
  addNode(node){
    ...
    if(node instanceOf Light){
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Node

```
// in Node.js
import NodeManager from '../../NodeManager.js'
class Node {
  constructor() {
    ...
    NodeManager.instance().addNode(this);
    ...
  }
}
```

Light

```
// in Light.js
import Node from '../../Node.js'
class Light extends Node {
  constructor() {
    super();        
    ...
  }
}
```

For some reason the import of Node in light does not work thus Light.js throws the error when calling super. I am uncertain of how to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you solved it? struggling with the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`super()` must be the first thing you call in the constructor (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31079103/1369676)). 
It seems like you're missing `super()` call in the constructor of the Node class.

Comment: No I call super I just left it out for brevity.