# Is there a way to use 'this' in the super() constructor?

Tags: typescript, constructor

I am looking at another person's code and in the code, they have code that is essentially this:

```
class foo extends bar {
    constructor() {
        super(param1, param2, new certainObject(this, otherParams));
    }
}
```

The problem I am having with this code is that it says gives the error that `'super' must be called before accessing 'this' in the constructor of a derived class`.

I am wondering: is there was a way to use `this` in the call to `super()` or am I going to have to completely restructure the code?

Comment: In which language is the code from the other person you looked at, written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a direct non-hackish way to use `this` before `super` call and not as a part of that call (and this is exactly what the error is telling you).

Here's what the [TypeScript book](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/classes.html#inheritance) says about it. There's also a related (not the same) [issue opened in GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8277) to allow at least some non `this` related code to be executed before `super`.

Comment: In fact, this is not anything that TypeScript can address.  It is part of the ES2015 spec, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31079103/2887218) describes.

Comment: @jcalz oh, good there's an answer already. Should we mark this question as "duplicate" then?

Comment: Hmm, well the question isn't exactly a duplicate of the other question because the other question is asking if they can skip `super()` entirely.  The accepted answer is very applicable here, though.

Comment: @jcalz you are right. I am not familiar with the strict criteria for a pair of questions to be considered duplicates...