# Is super(originalError) necessary when extending the Error object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, ecmascript-6, error-handling

When extending the `Error` object, I'm frustrated that calling `super(originalError)` results in a normal stack trace printed to STDOUT. I want my logs to be formatted in JSON so that they're consumable by logstash/Kibana. Stack traces in Kibana that include `\n` are split into multiple entries, as it does not really know what to do with that input apparently. I can avoid this through a little modification before logging

```
function logError(errorDetails, stack) {
  logger.error({ errorDetails, stack: sanitizeLineBreaks(stack) } // removes `\n`
}
```

However the error object I'm implementing which does this looks like:

```
class ServerError extends Error {
  constructor(originalError, errorDetails, stack) {
    super(originalError) // <- this is the problem
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, ServerError)
    // stuff ...
    logError(originalError, stack)
  }
}
```

However, calling `super(originalError)` prints to the console with new line characters; this makes for ugly entries where each line of the trace is a separate entry in the Kibana GUI. I'm not getting any complaints in the console when I do *not* call `super(originalError)`, but I am still hesitant to remove it.

#### Is `super(originalError)` necessary when extending the `Error` object?

Comment: `super()` does not print anything to the console?! It just creates the `Error` instance. Or do you have an overwritten `Error` constructor in your environment?

Comment: @Bergi `However calling super(originalError) prints to the console with new line characters` Seems like I've misled somewhere. Can you point to what made you think it didn't print anything?

Comment: @Bergi Hmm I am not totally following. `Super(originalError)` _does_ print to the console in my case.

Comment: @Bergi I only `extend` `Error`, not overwrite it.

Comment: Can you show a complete program that reproduces the problem? Creating a `new Error(…)` does not print anything to the console in my node - except when you do `console.log(new Error(…))`.

Comment: The only reason it'd print anything is if you're doing this from the console; constructing an error does no logging, AFAIK. In the console it just prints whatever the last value was. E.g., if you type `f = new Foo(new Error('hi')); null` it prints `null`, because that was the last evaled expr.

Comment: Does it still happen when you remove the `logError(originalError, stack)` from the constructor? A constructor should not do such a thing anyway, it should only initialise the instance.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I guess there's the part where it's explicitly logged :/

Comment: @Bergi yes it still logs the stack when I remove `logError(originalError, stack)`

Answer (score 1):

(Ignoring your issue with logging)

> Is `super(originalError)` necessary when extending the `Error` object?

Yes. [Every `class` that `extends` another and defines a custom `constructor` **must** call `super()` to create the instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31067368/1048572).

Comment: That does answer the question, so thank you. Do you know if there is any way to suppress it printing the error stack however?

Comment: Calling the `Error` constructor should not print anything anywhere. Please create a [mcve] in your question