# Making a new ES6 Object in another Object's constructor fails

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

**Edit**: *this question is different from [How to extend a class without having to using super in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31067368/how-to-extend-a-class-without-having-to-using-super-in-es6) - although the answers are related, this is very obviously a different question. It relates to a specific error, and the two main classes involved `Person` and `CreationEvent` don't actually inherit from each other.*

I have two ES6 classes, `Person` and `CreationEvent` (`CreationEvent` inherits from `Event`). I wish to to make a `new CreationEvent` when I make a `new Person` (as the `CreationEvent` is part of the events in the history of person's account).

**Running `new CreationEvent()` on it's own works fine. However I can't run `new Person()`.**

Even with reduced version of the code still fails:

```
class Event {
    constructor() {
        this.time = Date.now()
        this.tags = []
    }
}

class CreationEvent extends Event {
    constructor() {
        this.description = "Created"
    }
}

class Person {
    constructor(givenName, familyName, email) {
        var creationEvent = new CreationEvent()
    }
}
```

Running `new Person()` returns

> ReferenceError: Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor

**How do I make a new ES6 Object in another Object's constructor?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extend a class without having to using super in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31067368/how-to-extend-a-class-without-having-to-using-super-in-es6)

Comment: @JonathanGagne Have edited the comment to explain the difference.

Comment: Downvoters: care to explain why?

Comment: What did I have edited? I search over the history and I cannot found it.

Comment: @JonathanGagne I mean *I*, not you, have edited. I'm included your username because I'm responding to you!

Comment: Lol Aight thanks my friend!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `super()` in the `CreationEvent` class because it extends the `Event` class and needs te be initialized. Like this:

```
class CreationEvent extends Event {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.description = "Created"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But why does `new CreationEvent()` work without doing this? Also shouldn't a class that inherits from another class automatically run the constructor of the class it inherits from?

Comment: @mikemaccana `new CreationEvent()` also doesn't work without the `super()` call. It's required to manually call the super constructor because javascript doesn't know when and how you'd like to call it. This allows you to e.g. manipulate the arguments to the super call.

Comment: @jaap3 You're right, I'd copied and pasted and not edited it when I tested it earlier. Thanks!