# How to call function in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Cannot use a function from a child by reference.

```
export class Home extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    this.imageReference = React.createRef();
}

state = {
    fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0),
}

componentDidMount() {
    Animated.timing(
        this.state.fadeAnim,
        {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 2400,
            useNativeDriver: true
        }
    ).start(() => this.imageReference.current.initImageAnimation());
}

render() {
    let { fadeAnim } = this.state;

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Animated.View style={{
                opacity: fadeAnim,
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#7eb3e0',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center'
            }}>
                <Logo ref={this.imageReference} />
            </Animated.View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

> Error occures: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_this.imageReference = _react.default.createRef()')

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stackoverflow!  Please read this about a [MCVE], and edit your question to fit that mold.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're missing super() within the constructor for your instance properties to work:

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.imageReference = React.createRef();
}
```

This SO answer explains why in detail:
[How to extend a class without having to using super in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31067368/how-to-extend-a-class-without-having-to-using-super-in-es6/31079103#31079103)