# Is the call to super(props) in an ES6 class important?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Suppose I've the following class:

```
class Tabs extends React.Component {
  displayName: Tabs;

  static propTypes = {
  selected: React.PropTypes.number,
  children: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
    React.PropTypes.array,
    React.PropTypes.element
  ]).isRequired
  };

  constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    selected: 0,
    maxSelected: 0
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
       {this.props.selected}
       {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

I want to know that if passing the following constructor is important:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}
```

My current code works just fine but I wanted to know if this is a good practice.

Comment: No it's not, in fact there's even an eslint rule to disallow this http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-useless-constructor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between "super()" and "super(props)" in React when using es6 classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571875/whats-the-difference-between-super-and-superprops-in-react-when-using-e)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to [Sophie Alpert with the React team](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/should-we-include-the-props-parameter-to-class-constructors-when-declaring-components-using-es6-classes/2781) it's only necessary to pass props into the constructor if you intend on using `this.props` inside the constructor. After the constructor is invoked, React attaches the props to the component from the outside.

Comment: I'm new to react, are you saying like. If im going to use props in my current component, in that case only I need to use super(props) in constructor??

Comment: @usama super(props) is unnecessary in constructor until unless you're gonna do some work in the constructor level. In ES2015every class has default constructor so it's unnecessary to have empty one.