# Why can't I access default props in react constructor, but I can in render?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, ecmascript-6

Per the title, why does the initial this.props fail? And more practically, how do you work around this in cases where you rely on the props within your constructor? For instance I would like to reference props within my subscriptions?

```
class AboutBox extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    title: 'Undefined Product',
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log(this.props.title); //this fails (=> null)
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.title); //this works (=> 'Undefined Product')
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30571875/2088135

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between "super()" and "super(props)" in React when using es6 classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571875/whats-the-difference-between-super-and-superprops-in-react-when-using-e)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put the props on the constructor args, and pass them to super

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log(props.title);
}
```

use props inside constructor, this works also, but have some problem in transpilation against IE

Answer (score 1):

Try adding props to the `constructor()` parameters and to the `super()` call:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  console.log(props.title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `this.props` in the constructor, you need to pass `props` to `super()`. Otherwise, it doesn't matter because React sets `.props` on the instance from the outside immediately after calling the constructor.