# what does super() do without any arguments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, super

I'm learning react from the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html), but not sure what the `super()` does in this example. Usually, doesn't it take the arguments that are passed to making a new instance and then calls React.Component's constructor method to incorporate these arguments into the instance? What does it do without any arguments?

```
class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      liked: false
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({liked: !this.state.liked});
  }
  render() {
    const text = this.state.liked ? 'liked' : 'haven\'t liked';
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
        You {text} this. Click to toggle.
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <LikeButton />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Comment: super(), in most class based languages means call the parent's constructor.   So it would be calling React.Component's constructor.

Comment: Does the super constructor have default arguments (implicit or otherwise) that would allow zero arguments to make sense? This seems like it could be solved by looking at the source code.

Comment: React.Component constructor takes one argument https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes

Comment: I believe this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34995257/1517783

Answer (score 56):

In ES6, derived classes have to call `super()` if they have a constructor. In react, all components extend from the Component class.

You don't actually need a constructor for every ES6/react class. If no custom constructor is defined, it will use the [default constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor#Default_constructors). For base classes, it is:

```
constructor() {}
```

And for derived classes, the default constructor is:

```
constructor(...args) {
  super(...args);
}
```

You also need to call `super()` before accessing `this`, since `this` is not initialized until `super()` is called.

There are a few reasons to use a custom constructor in react. One is that you can set the initial state within the constructor using `this.state = ...` instead of using the `getInitialState` lifecycle method.

You can also bind class methods inside the constructor with `this.someClassMethod = this.someClassMethod.bind(this)`. It's actually better to bind methods in the constructor since they will only be created once. Otherwise if you call `bind` or use arrow functions to bind methods anywhere outside the constructor (like in the `render` method), it will actually end up creating a new instance of the function on every render. Read more about that [here](https://medium.com/@rjun07a/binding-callbacks-in-react-components-9133c0b396c6).

If you want to use `this.props` in the constructor, you need to call `super` with props as an argument:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
}
```

If you don't, then `this.props` is undefined in the constructor. However, you can still access `this.props` anywhere else in the class outside the constructor without needing to do anything with it in the constructor.

Answer (score 28):

The `super` keyword in JavaScript is used in order to call the methods of the parent class. By itself, `super()` is used within a constructor function to call the parent constructor function. For example:

```js
class Animal {
  
  constructor(age) {
    console.log('Animal being made');
    this.age = age;
  }
  
  returnAge() {
    return this.age;
  }
  
}

class Dog extends Animal {

  constructor (age){
    super(age);
  }
  
  logAgeDog () {
    console.log(`This dog is: ${ super.returnAge()} years old`);
  }
  
}

const dog = new Dog(5);


console.log(dog);

dog.logAgeDog();
```

In this example we have a Dog class which `extends` an Animal class. The Dog class uses the `super` keyword twice. The first occurence is in the constructor, when `super()` is used in the constructor it will call the parent class constructor. Therefore we have to give the age property as an argument to it. Now the Dog successfully has an age property.

We can also use `super` outside of the constructor in order to access the parent's 'class' (i.e. prototype) properties and methods. We use this in the `logAgeDog` function located in the Dog class. We use the following code:

```
super.returnAge();
```

You should read this as:

```
Animal.returnAge();     // superClass.returnAge()
```

### Why do I need this in React?

You need the `super()` keyword in React **only** when implementing a constructor. You have to do the following:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  // Don't call this.setState() here!
}
```

the parent class which is named `Component` needs to do some initialization on its own in order for React to work fine. If you implement a constructor without a `super(props)` call `this.props` in `Component` will be `undefined` which can lead to bugs.