# When to use constructor and super in Polymer 2.0?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

The following pattern is used a lot when building Polymer 2.0 ES6 web components.

```
constructor() {
  super();
}
```

[Here the documentation describes calling the `super();` function when defining an element.](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements)

[However here in the Shop App](https://github.com/Polymer/shop/tree/master/src) the pattern is only followed 3 times, in the following elements: shop-app.html, shop-ripple-container.html, shop-tabs-overlay.html.

When do we need to call `super()`? When does this call need to be inside the `constructor()` function? And what are the consequences of not calling `super()` as appears in the case of [the Shop app](https://github.com/Polymer/shop/tree/master/src)?

Edit:
A user (@4castle) suggested this question [might be a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822941/what-does-super-do-with-any-arguments). I respectfully disagree. This question deals with Polymer, whereas the other deals with React. The other question asks about arguments passed to the `super()` function. This question wants to know what happens when `super()` is not called and where the best place to call is (i.e., inside `constructor()` or not).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does super() do with any arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822941/what-does-super-do-with-any-arguments)

Comment: `super()` is required when a class `extends` another class. Otherwise, it will throw a `ReferenceError` if you try to access `this` without first calling `super()`.

Comment: @4castle: I added and answer based on your comment and the other question you pointed to. I also edited the question to explain why I think it's different. Please let me know if you think I'm on the right track or not if you wouldn't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When do we need to call `super()`?

`super()` calls the constructor of the element's *superclass* (parent class). If an element's definition defines a class that extends another class and `super()` is not called explicitly, the element calls the constructor of the superclass by default.

> When does this call need to be inside the `constructor()` function?

The proper place to call `super()` is inside the element's `constructor()` method.

> And what are the consequences of not calling `super()` as appears in the case of the Shop app?

In the case where,

```
class MyElement extends Polymer.Element {...}
```

as in the case of the Shop App — the `Polymer.Element` constructor is called by default if `super()` is not called explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

In fact it's also good practice to invoke the following to get the full benefit of your super (parent):

```
ready() {
  super.ready();
}
```

That will invoke the ready function in Element when your component is ready.