# How to set state from props that is passed to the component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this simple component, `initialPlayers` props is passed to `App` component.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var PLAYERS = [
  {
    name: "xyz",
    score: 123
  }
];

// App component
class App extends React.Component {

 constructor() {
   super();
 }

 componentDidMount() {
   this.state = {
     players: this.props.initialPlayers
   }
 }

 render() {    
   return(
     <div>
       <Header players={this.state.players} />
     </div>
   );
 }
}

// Render component
ReactDOM.render(<App initialPlayers={ PLAYERS }/>, 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Have this error in console, and not able to pass value to `Header` component as `{this.state.players}`. Any idea?.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'players' of null
at App.render (bundle.js:14379)
at bundle.js:20173
at measureLifeCyclePerf (bundle.js:19452)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (bundle.js:20172)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (bundle.js:20199)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (bundle.js:19739)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js:19635)
at Object.mountComponent (bundle.js:4667)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (bundle.js:19748)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (bundle.js:19635)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React component initialize state from props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063468/react-component-initialize-state-from-props)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move the setting players line into your constructor():

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    players: this.props.initialPlayers
  };
}
```

Comment: This is how Facebook does it as shown in their documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Comment: Wow this is so obvious now, I need to alter state on a previous screen and this works perfect

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`componentWillMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) because it runs **before** the component's first render – compare that to the description of [`componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

```js
var PLAYERS = [
  { name: "xyz", score: 123 },
  { name: 'abc', score: 111 },
  { name: 'def', score: 222 }
];

const Header = ({players}) =>
  <ul>{players.map(({name,score}) =>
    <li><span>{name}</span><span>{score}</span></li>)}</ul>

// App component
class App extends React.Component {

  // get rid of constructor if you're not doing anything with it
  // constructor() { ... }

  // use componentWillMount instead of componentDidMount
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      players: this.props.initialPlayers
    })
  }

  // don't wrap everything in a div if it's not necessary
  render() {    
    return <Header players={this.state.players} />
  }
}

// Render component
ReactDOM.render(<App initialPlayers={ PLAYERS }/>, 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

span ~ span {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to initialize your `state` otherwise you'll get error updating it's value, then you have to use `setState` method to change it (this is the recommended way to update `state` in react)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var PLAYERS = [
  {
    name: 'xyz',
    score: 123
  }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      players: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      players: this.props.initialPlayers
    });
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.renderPlayers()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
  renderPlayers() {
    return this.state.players.map((player, index) =>
      <li key={index}>{`name: ${player.name} - score: ${player.score}`}</li>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App initialPlayers={ PLAYERS }/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Wrong use of componentDidMount, ESlint itself throws an error for this. Instead, componentWillMount should be used.

Comment: Yep you are right, in this case the best choice would be **componentWillMount**