# How should I handle component state following single responsibility pattern

Tags: reactjs, single-responsibility-principle, react-component

I'm new to ReactJs and trying to follow best practices. From my research, I've come across a couple of contradicting articles discussing how implementation should be.

**Should state rely on the properties being passed down from a parent component? In the comparisons below, they are both following SRP, but not sure which is best. Would like your advice, Thanks!**

## 1. -- [Best Practices for Component State in React.js](http://brewhouse.io/blog/2015/03/24/best-practices-for-component-state-in-reactjs.html)

> First, and probably the most important of all, the state of a component should not depend on the props passed in. (see below for example of what we should not do)

```
class UserWidget extends React.Component {
  // ...

  // BAD: set this.state.fullName with values received through props
  constructor (props) {
    this.state = {
      fullName: `${props.firstName} ${props.lastName}`
    };
  }
  // ...
}
```

## 2. -- [7 architectural attributes of a reliable React component](https://dmitripavlutin.com/7-architectural-attributes-of-a-reliable-react-component/#13casestudyhocfavorssingleresponsibilityprinciple)

> Let's refactor  to have one responsibility: render form fields and attach event handlers. It shouldn't know how to use storage directly.....The component receives the stored input value from a prop initialValue, and saves the input value using a prop function saveValue(newValue). These props are provided by withPersistence() HOC using props proxy technique.

```
class PersistentForm extends Component {  
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { inputValue: props.initialValue };
    }
    // ...
}
```

## 3. -- In my case, I have something like the following (wondering if this is an acceptable implementation?) - Should state be handled in Tasks, or in another TasksWithPersistence type of component that sits between TasksWithData and Tasks?

```
export default function TasksWithData(TasksComponent) {  

    return class withData extends React.Component {
        render() {
            const tasks = TaskAPI.getTasks();
            return (
                <TasksComponent 
                    tasks={tasks} 
                    {...this.props} 
                />
            )
        }
    }

}


export default class Tasks extends React.Component {

    state = { 
        tasks: [], 
        addItemInput: null 
    };

    // ...

    componentDidMount() {
        this.updateComponentState({tasks: this.props.tasks});
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.prepUIForNextAddition();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063468/react-component-initialize-state-from-props As a learner I am avoiding setting state in constructor. Generally I use them directly without getting involve the state. If you really need to change those props and hold them in the state you can do this componentDidMount maybe.

Comment: Thanks, but not really what I was hoping to get from it. I follow the first class example from that post. In the above examples I provided, they're not doing that, but the concept is the same. I'm more concerned with whether a child component should set state, in my case, in the componentDidMount lifecycle method, with the props that are being passed down or whether that's a No-No.

Comment: If you need you can set a state in Child. But, if you don't need to mutate its props and use them locally in the state without depending Parent why do you need to to use state? Situation is like that: If you don't mutate props do not set them in your state, even do not use state or class based component if you don't need any state or lifecylce in your Child component. This is how I do as a learner like you.

Comment: I added to my initial question (see #3) --- Agreed, if state doesn't need to be changed, then just use the props and forget about setting state.

Comment: You are using HOC here, so its only duty seems passing the data. Maybe handling the state in Tasks is the right situation here. At least this is how I would do. But, again I'm some kind of newbie, more suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gist of your question seems to revolve around the [anti-pattern](https://shripadk.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html) that is to take some *props* and duplicate it into the *state*. This, mutating of props, isn't the purpose of the state. Props are immutable, duping them to the state defeats this design.

The purpose of the state is to manage things that are specific to the React Component, i.e. tightly scoped to only that React component. For instance a showHide switch for something to display within the React component. Think of the state as a locally scoped variable if it helps.

Most of the time this anti-pattern of duping the props can be satisfied by a function within the React object. For example, your state.full_name variable becomes a named function, fullName, bound to the React Component. (all code examples are assuming JSX syntax)

*Note: in JavaScript camelcase is the naming structure for functions and variables, I'm assuming you're coming from ruby based on the underscore naming convention. IMO it's best to stick to the convention of the language with which you're writing the code. This is why I use camelcased naming.*

```
...
fullName() {
    return this.props.firstName + " " + this.props.lastName
} 
...
```

That function can then be called within the render of the component

```
# in render() portion of your React component, assuming jsx syntax
<p>Hello, {this.fullName()}</p>
```

*Note: Remember that in ES6 you have to [bind the methods in your react class](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9851) in the constructor or use => syntax so that you can call them with this.*

```
...
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.fullName = this.fullName.bind(this);
}
...
```

You could also decompose the relevant parts to a new Component called *FullName* if it will be utilized by multiple components.

```
<FullName firstName={this.props.firstName} lastName={this.props.lastName} />
```

Technically, "the react way" is, at least in this author's opinion, to decompose this into another component for reusability. However component reuse needs to be weighed against the complexity added, i.e. don't optimize prematurely. So you may not want to take that too far at first. The times when it's necessary will emerge naturally.

A very broad generalization of React's props is that they are guaranteed, are immutable, and they flow down like a waterfall from the topmost component. If you need to update them, update them at the highest level where it makes sense.

In a soley React based approach, if you have something that a parent needs to be aware of, "lift" that part of the code up to the parent and vice versa bind it down to the child as a props, e.g. an AJAX function that calls an API. I think of it as trying to keep the components as *dumb* as possible.

The parent becomes the "source of truth" for the item you "lifted". The parent handles the updates, and then passes the results to the children. So in the parent, it may exist as a state variable and then get passed as props to the child object, which then passes it along as props to it's child object, etc. The children would update as the state gets changed in their parent when it propagates down through the chain as props.

If your app is React only, i.e. no stores that manage objects such as in the flux pattern or redux pattern, you may have to store things in the topmost objet's state which technically could be viewed as bad. As your system becomes more complex, this functionality would be better handled by flux or redux's parts.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You mention that I come from Ruby based on underscore, which I didn't include in any part of this example (not sure if you copied from elsewhere), but no, I have never worked with Ruby. I appreciate the extra information and the basis behind React methodologies.

Comment: just a guess as ruby is one of the few popular languages with underscore syntax on variables, but by no means the only one. GLHF with react! :)

Comment: thanks! Out of curiosity, where did you see underscores on my variable names? Perhaps I've been looking at my code for too long, lol.

Comment: OMG you're right. I blame afternoon brain. I must have had another problem on my mind when I wrote that! haha

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge difference between example 1 & 2.

In example #1, the reason it's bad to set state from the those props in that way is that if the props change, the widget will not update. Best practices or not, that is just wrong and bad in any framework. In that particular case, there really is no point in even using the state. Props alone will suffice.

In example #2 the prop is only being used to give the state an initial value (The prop is even named `initialValue`), implying that further changes to the state will be controlled by the component regardless of prop changes.  It does not break single responsibility principle to use props for an initial state, especially when it's explicitly use for that purpose.

I really don't see those two examples as being contradictory because they are completely different. Further, there is no rule in single responsibility principle that you can't set state from props, you just need to pay attention to the context in which you are doing it.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose I found them contradictory due to the setting of state by properties, which was the main purpose of my question. I see one avenue where one is saying props shouldn't set state, but then i see another where that is happening.