# Mapping an object array into a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an API that gives an error response in this form
[image]

In reactJS I am able to pass the parameters by using this.props.errors to my child component, but now I want to map this.props.errors into the child component as below

```
state = {
 slug: '', 
 name: '', 
 address_1: '', 
 address_2: '', 
 city: '', 
 state: '', 
 postal_code: '', 
 country_code: '', 
 phone_number: '',
}
```

meaning, I want the elements of the error parameter to be placed in a child component's state per element. How do I do that?

Comment: Please show us your parent component and how do you communicate with child component.

Comment: @Liam sorry changed the question when I noticed how stupid my error was as to why it won't pass the information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React component initialize state from props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063468/react-component-initialize-state-from-props)

Answer (score 0):

Save your response in customizing as per your requirement. As per code snippet. save it in state and pass this state to children. by using `componentWillReceiveProps` update child state.

example: [working Code with React](https://codesandbox.io/s/j4kjj9kkvw)

```js
let response = {
      slug: ['slug required'],
      name: ['name'],
      address_1: ['address_1'],
      address_2: ['address_2'],
      city: ['city'],
      state: ['state'],
      postal_code: ['postal_code'],
      country_code: ['country_code'],
      phone_number: ['phone_number ']
    } 
    const keys = Object.keys(response)
    keys.map((m)=>{
      response[m] = Array.isArray(response[m]) ? response[m][0] : response[m]
    })
    console.log("customed response",response)
```