# What is the best way to handle default values in controlled components?

Tags: reactjs

I have a UserModal which is both used for insert and editing a user. On my `<input>` element I have both specified the `value` prop which uses the state and the `defaultValue` prop which uses the username props if it is not null.

```
<input
  type="text"
  className="form-control"
  id="username"
  tabIndex={1}
  required={true}
  onChange={this.handleOnUsernameChange}
  value={this.state.username}
  defaultValue={this.props.username || ''} />
```

> UserModal contains an input of type number with both value and
>   defaultValue props. Input elements must be either controlled or
>   uncontrolled (specify either the value prop, or the defaultValue prop,
>   but not both). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input
>   element and remove one of these props.

If I use the `<input>` element snippet from above then I get the warning/error message printed in the console. What are the best practices for handling situations where the default value is required with controlled component? Or is it easier/better to do this with an uncontrolled component?

Answer (score 0):

Use a controlled component. You can set your default prop in the state.

```
this.state = {
   username: this.state.username || this.props.username
};

this.onChange = this.handleOnUsernameChange.bind(this);

<input
   type="text"
   className="form-control"
   id="username"
   tabIndex={1}
   required={true}
   onChange={this.handleOnUsernameChange}
   value={this.state.username}
/>

handleOnUsernameChange = e => {
   this.setState({
      username: e.target.value
   });
   console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

Comment: Initializing the state based on the props is a anti-pattern; https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e

Comment: Interesting... personally I never encountered a problem this way. Might be because it's being used to set the initial value if there's no value in the state. In this case I don't think there's going to be a side effect as the component is not relying on the prop to perform anything other than display the initial value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063468/react-component-initialize-state-from-props