# Send state/props to another component in React with onClick

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-props, setstate, buttonclick

I have two separate components, which don't have a simple parent-child relationship.

```
ComponentFolderA 
|
ButtonComponent 

ComponentFolderB
|
BannerComponent
```

I want to `setState` when the user clicks on the button and send that value to the `BannerComponent`

What's the best way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In functional components, you can create a state in a parent component for both ButtonComponent and BannerComponent. Then do as the following example,

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [sampleState, setSampleState] = useState(null);

    return (
      <>
          <BannerComponent sampleState={sampleState} />
          <ButtonComponent setSampleState={setSampleState} />
      </>
    )
}
```

Then you can access the setSampleState as a prop inside the ButtonComponent.

Also, check this out [Best practice way to set state from one component to another in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53035445/best-practice-way-to-set-state-from-one-component-to-another-in-react) and you can use a state manager ([Context API](https://www.toptal.com/react/react-context-api), [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start))

Answer (score 1):

Keep state in the parent and send the state setting function down to your Button.

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <>
      <BannerComponent myState={myState} />
      <ComponentWithButton setMyState={setMyState} />
    </>
  )
}

const ComponentWithButton = props => {
  return (
    <Button onClick={() => props.setMyState(true)} />
  )
}
```