# Can not set state with props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to map over an array that I get from parent component but the problem is that even though I assign the data to state, on the initial load state is empty and that results me having an empty array. I need this array in the state because I will be implementing a sorting functionality into my project and I would like to change `userData` whenever user clicks on corresponding cell. Here is the code I have :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
const UserTable = ({ repoData }) => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState(repoData);
    console.log(repoData)

    const descending = [].concat(repoData)
        .sort((a, b) => a.name < b.name ? 1 : -1);

    const ascending = [].concat(repoData)
        .sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1);

    function clickHandler() {
        setUserData(descending)
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Table sortable celled fixed>
                <Table.Header>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.HeaderCell
                            onClick={clickHandler}
                        >
                            Repository Name
        </Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell

                        >
                            Description
        </Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell

                        >
                            Created At
        </Table.HeaderCell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Header>
                <Table.Body>
                    {userData.map(repos => {
                        return <Table.Row>

                            <Table.Cell>{repos.name}</Table.Cell>
                            <Table.Cell>{repos.description}</Table.Cell>
                            <Table.Cell> <Moment format="DD-MM-YYYY">{repos.created_at}</Moment></Table.Cell>
                        </Table.Row>
                    })}


                </Table.Body>
            </Table>
        </div>
    );
}

export default UserTable;
```

Comment: Does that `console.log` initially show anything?

Comment: Beware of the dreaded init-state-with-props-anti-pattern :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/47341539/2295549, it could bite you later.

Comment: First two logs are empty then the second two logs are filled with what I need @ElAoutarHamza

Comment: Does it still counted as anti-pattern if I would create instance of that prop? What would be your suggestion to come over that problem? @Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first logs are empty this means that the parent component passes an empty array to `UserTable`.

If you dont want `UserTable` to show when `repoData` is still empty, you can do that at the parent level by checking that `repoData` is defined and has a length > 0.

```
const App = () => {
  ...

  return (
      <>
          ...
          {repoData && repoData.length ? <UserTable repoData={repoData} /> : null (or something else)}
          ...
      </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This logical approach solved my problem.