# Prefill form data in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a form component in my react app that can be used to create or update recipes depending on the route. The create functionality works fine, but the update is giving me trouble.

I pass fetched data into the component using `props` here is what the JSON looks like:

```
{
   method: "Cook the guanciale in a large skillet over medium heat until deeply golden 
           (adjust the heat as necessary to render the fat [...]
   name: "Pasta Alla Gricia"
}
```

I am trying to get the `name` to prefill into the form's `name` `<input>` and the method to prefill into the form's `method` `<textarea>`. I tried doing this with `useEffect()`, with:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setName(props.data.name)
    setMethodStepsList(props.data.method)
  })
```

while it prefilled the `name` input it then locked the value to that. The method did not prefill the `textarea` at all.

I am pretty stumped with this one, and would be grateful for any assistance.

```
export default function Recipe(props) {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [methodStepsList, setMethodStepsList] = useState('')
  const [methodStepObject, setMethodStepObject] = useState([])
  const [ingredientList, setIngredientList] = useState([])
  const [ingredientObject, setIngredientObject] = useState({
    ingredient_name: '',
    quantity: '',
    measure: '',
  })

  const formLabel = props.data ? 'Update Recipe' : 'New Recipe'
  useEffect(() => {
    setName(props.data.name)
    setMethodStepsList(props.data.method)
  })

  //new recipe logic
  [...]

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="recipe-form-container">
        <form className="recipe-form">
          <div className="page-header">
            <h1>{formLabel}</h1>
          </div>

          {/* recipe name logic */}
          <div className="recipe-title recipe-element">
            <label>Recipe Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              value={name}
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
            ></input>
          </div>

          //recipe method logic
          <div className="recipe-blurb recipe-element">
            <label>Recipe Method</label>
            <span className="method-span">
              <textarea
                rows="5"
                name="step_instructions"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Method will be split up based on new lines"
                onChange={(e) => handleMethodChange(e)}
              ></textarea>
              <button
                onClick={(e) => {
                  console.log(methodStepObject)
                  setMethodStepsList(methodStepObject)
                  e.preventDefault()
                }}
              >
                Add Method
              </button>
          
         [...]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `useEffect` statements and try like this

```
const [name, setName] = useState(props.data.name)
const [methodStepsList, setMethodStepsList] = useState(props.data.method)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It looks like the props get passed down from the parent component twice, once they are empty objects and the second time they have the data. You can see [here](https://ibb.co/r25KfdN) so it initializes as empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful while initializing state with props in React.
See [React component initialize state from props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063468/react-component-initialize-state-from-props)

```
class Recipe extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {name:'', method:'', ingredients: []};
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props,state) {
        return {name: props.data.name, method: props.data.method};
    }

    render() {
        return <div>...</div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use useRef and useEffect to populate data in the form from an object.

```
const AddArticle = ({ submitArticle, editData, editChangedArticle }) => {

    const [article, setArticle] = useState(undefined);

    const titleRef = useRef('');
    const bodyRef = useRef('');
    const idRef = useRef('');

    useEffect(() => {
        prepopulateForm(editData);
    }, [editData])

    const prepopulateForm = (editData) => {
        if (editData) {
            idRef.current.value = editData.id;
            titleRef.current.value = editData.title;
            bodyRef.current.value = editData.body || '';
        }
    }

    const handleChange = e => {
        setArticle({
            ...article,
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        });
    }

    const addNewArticle = e => {
        // stop submission of the form and to prevent the browser from refreshing itself when it encounters a native submit
        e.preventDefault();
        submitArticle(article);
    }

    const editNewArticle = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // console.log(editData, article, {...editData, ...article});
        const newObj = { ...editData, ...article };
        editChangedArticle(newObj);
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={!!editData?.id ? editNewArticle : addNewArticle}>
            <input ref={idRef} id="id" onChange={handleChange} readOnly />
            <input ref={titleRef} id="title" type="text" placeholder="Enter title" onChange={handleChange} />
            <input ref={bodyRef} id="body" type="text" placeholder="Enter body" onChange={handleChange} />
            <button type="submit">{editData?.id ? 'Save changes' : 'Add Article'}</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default AddArticle
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-i9ad7e?file=README.md