# Can someone explain the 'super()' keyword in ES6 Javascript (especially related to React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm learning React.js, and I see the `super` keyword used a lot in constructor functions.

I understand that `super` allows a subclass to have access to the `this` keyword. However, I can't find much more explanation.

- Why does calling `super()`, magically give my class access to `this`?
- Why does the `super` keyword bind `this` to the context of the class?
- When I'm not dealing with a subclass, why don't I have to call
  `super()`?

Comment: You can look up keywords and most other things on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super)

Answer (score 7):

Sorry for the pic in Japanese, but looks easy to understand.

When you use `super` function in your class member functions, `extends` keyword is also expected to be used. When you call super like `super(args)` in the **extending** class, it calls the constructor of the **extended** class. You can also call the other member functions of the **extended** class with `super.methods(args)`, not `super(args)`.

[image: extends and super]
(From https://liginc.co.jp/266587)

**UPDATE**

FYI: [What's the difference between "super()" and "super(props)" in React when using es6 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571875/whats-the-difference-between-super-and-superprops-in-react-when-using-e)
This discussion explains well about how `super` in react component affects this context constraint. Good to read.

Comment: You cannot use `super(arg)` in methods, it needs to be `super.methods(arg)`.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, a `super` call in the constructor calls the constructor of the parent class. You can have access to `this` independently of using it or not, but in the context of react, this properties associated with `this`, like `this.props` and `this.state` are set and configured properly in the `React.Component` class constructor. So that's why you must call super first, so that `this` is properly setup.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm going to play around a little with using 'this' to test how super() sets it up, but that makes alot more conceptual sense.

Comment: so following this logic,  we would assume super() could be avoid using an arrow function since the arrow function will automatically be translucent to the parent's context?

Comment: @Webwoman, I don't think it makes sense for the constructor to be an arrow function, because on a constructor you will most certainly desire use a `this` reference... Maybe I didn't understood what you meant...

Comment: @LuanNico I mean ES6 arrow functions can't be bound to a this keyword, so it will lexically go up a scope, and use the value of this in the scope in which it was defined, in this case, the component itself ? https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiFqI3exKPhAhUByIUKHYjBDHAQFjACegQIDBAL&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.freecodecamp.org%2Fwhen-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26&usg=AOvVaw2zB96UnxxpF8uPjuL_rl3K. 

that was just to make some theoretical assumption :).