# Passing parameters in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to navigate between a master detail data format in React.  The source page does this:

```
{myDataList.map(myData =>
    <tr key={myData.dataId}>
    <td>{myData.dataId}</td>
    <td>{myData.dataDescription}</td>
    <td>
        <NavLink to={'/details/' + myData.dataId}>
            Details
        </NavLink>
    </td>
```

Clicking the edit link does navigate to the details page with the correct URL; which does this (mainly taken from the example template in VS):

```
interface DetailsState {
    details?: DataDetails;
    loading: boolean;
}

export class Details extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<number>, DetailsState> {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { details: undefined, loading: true };

    console.log("match params: " + this.props.match.params);

    fetch('api/Data/Details/' + this.props.match.params)
        .then(response => response.json() as Promise<DataDetails>)
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ details: data, loading: false });
        });
}
```

My problem is that the console.log like above shows:

```
TypeError: _this.props is undefined
```

And so I can't access the `dataId` that I'm passing through.

Clearly I'm passing (or receiving) this parameter incorrectly; so my question is: what is the correct way to pass the parameter?  It's worth noting that my project is based on the VS Template, and I am using tsx, rather than jsx files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Diff between super(props) and super()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571875/whats-the-difference-between-super-and-superprops-in-react-when-using-e?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access `this.props` in a component's constructor. However, it is available as the first parameter. You can do this:

```
export class Details extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<number>, DetailsState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { details: undefined, loading: true };

    console.log("match params: " + props.match.params);

    fetch('api/Data/Details/' + props.match.params)
      .then(response => response.json() as Promise<DataDetails>)
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ details: data, loading: false });
      });
  }
}
```

Make sure that you call `super(props)` as the first thing in the constructor, or else React will yell at you.

**EDIT:**

As @Dan notes, it's generally not avisable to perform asynchronous actions in the constructor. Better to do that in `componentDidMount()`:

```
export class Details extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<number>, DetailsState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { details: undefined, loading: true };

    console.log("match params: " + props.match.params);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('api/Data/Details/' + this.props.match.params)
      .then(response => response.json() as Promise<DataDetails>)
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ details: data, loading: false });
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do network requests in the constructor. It's encouraged to do so in `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely true. I was aiming to give the minimal edits possible to answer @pm_2's question. But I will add a clarification.

Comment: Because it's typescript - it wants a type for `props`, but as far as I'm concerned - props is just a `number`?

Comment: Regarding the network request - that's straight from the MS template

Comment: There's nothing technically wrong with it AFAIK (though I might be wrong), since you're using `setState()` in the callback to the `fetch`, but it's just generally recommended to do any asynchronous things in  `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the types. If you don't care about the props, you can use `RouteComponentProps<any>`, but you might as well type them correctly. If you're confused about what the types should look like, then that's a topic for a separate question.

Comment: Thanks - I've defined the constructor `props` as RouteComponentProps<number>, since that's what's being passed in; however `console.log("match: " + this.props.match.params);` just returns `object`.  How do I extract the ID from that?

Comment: That depends on the definition of the `Route` that renders `Details`. If the `path` prop of that `Route` is `/details/:id` You should be able to access the `id` in `this.props.match.params.id`. But if you have other router-specific questions, that might be worth moving to a separate question. SO is warning me about how long this comments thread is getting.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I managed to get this to work by defining an interface that contains a single property of ID

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access `props` in your constructor, you need to pass them in:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
```