# React vs Redux props on the 'constructor' and 'super'

Tags: reactjs, redux

Why do I have 'props' passed as parameter in ReactJS and it doesn't  happen when I use ReduxJS?

for example:

React app:

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      memeLimit: 10
    }
 }
```

Redux app:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      memeLimit: 10
    }
 }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason to use `super(props);` is to be able to use `this.props` inside the constructor, otherwise you don't need `super(props);`

For example

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      memeLimit: this.props.memeLimit // Here you can use this.props
    }
 }
```

This is equivalent to

```
 constructor(props){
    super();
    this.state = {
      memeLimit: props.memeLimit // Here you cannot use this.props
    }
 }
```

This not really related to Redux Vs React

You can check this for more details: [What's the difference between "super()" and "super(props)" in React when using es6 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571875/whats-the-difference-between-super-and-superprops-in-react-when-using-e)