# Is super(props) necessary?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, react-native, react-props

I was looking at Facebook React Native documentation and I saw super(props) in constructor in [State](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html) part.

I [found that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34995257/4293498) we use super(props) only if we want to access props in constructor.

My question, isn't it unnecessary to use props in here then?

```
class Blink extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {isShowingText: true};

  // Toggle the state every second
  setInterval(() => {
   this.setState(previousState => {
    return { isShowingText: !previousState.isShowingText };
  });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: as you found *we use super(props) only if we use props in constructor.*, that means in your case its not required :)

Comment: Yeah.But I confused because, even though in the documentation they didn't use props in constructor, they used it in super()  :)

Comment: check this 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571875/whats-the-difference-between-super-and-superprops-in-react-when-using-e?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I already mentioned it in my question :))

Comment: If you are planning to override constructor then do call `super(props)` for the sake of future compatibillity. Who knows what base component constructor would do to it. But constructor should be kept as simple as possible. So, a better approach would be to move state initialization to class property initializer. And `setInterval` part to component lifecycle methods where it belongs to. For example you need to clear interval when component got unmounted (now you don't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not necessary.You can have a class component that has only a render in it.

example:

```
class EventsContainer extends React.Component {
 render() {
 const futurEvents = getFuturEvents(this.props.events);
 const passedEvents = getPassedEvents(this.props.events);

 return this.props.loggedIn
 ? <div>
     <NavbarContainer />
     <Events
       futurEvents={futurEvents}
       passedEvents={passedEvents}
       deleteEventInStateAndDB={this.props.deleteEventInStateAndDB}
     />
   </div>
 : <Redirect push to='/'/>
 }
}
```