# constructor/super/bind in React usage's what do they specify does?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend

I looked up what does `constructor`, `super` and `bind` does in General JS.

Example code.

```
import React from 'react';

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { mood: confused }   
    this.doNothing = this.doNothing.bind(this);
  }

  doNothing(){} //I really do nothing

  render(){
    <button onClick={this.doNothing}>I do nothing xD</button>
  }
}
```

Here is what I understand for now

1. `State` is an object, in order to create an object within a class I need to use `constructor`
2. subclass's `constructor` will override the parent's `constructor`, I don't know what is in `React.Component` but I am sure it is important. I think it is also said in React Document:

   > Class components should always call the base constructor with props.
3. `super` will help me do inherit, and `super` is the replacement of the parent's `constructor`. If I need to use `this` in `constructor` I need to write `super` and to go further, I need to pass a parament do `super(props)` to use `this.props`
4. `bind`will create a new function that is bounded well with the object, making sure when the function is called, it will be direct to the right object because for some reason if I don't bind it, my button will be like `<button onClick={undefined.doNothing}>`, because of some class rule :/ (the optional paraments can also help me set pre arguments which are interesting but that isn't what bothers me)

Here is what I don't understand

1. The meaning of arguments I passed, I have seen some example but they didn't really pass any argument. (The `props` `constructor(props)` `super(props)`)
2. The whole bind code looks odd to me, `this.doNothing` is changed into what? `this.this.doNothing`? How does it really works, why my button knows where to find it?

I know this is kinda basic but I did try my best looking things up, I will appreciate if anyone can help me out.

Comment: 1) you mean `props` ? 2) you explained that yourslef in 4)

Comment: @Jonas W. 1) I think I mean `this.state` I was learning it just now and codecademy was not specific at all :( 2) I don't know there is a connection between them, I will look up more about class inherit

Comment: No I mean your questions 1) 2) not what you understand already (which is all right, by the way)

Comment: Oh, Yeah I don;t understand the `props` I have to wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > State is an object, in order to create an object within a class I need
   >   to use constructor

You can create whatever object inside a class. Just that `state` is a special one in React: it need to be defined in constructor to be used in React component life-cycle.

2. > subclass's constructor will override the parent's constructor, I don't
   >   know what is in React.Component but I am sure it is important.

constructor, to my understanding, has three jobs: (1) allows access to `this.props` by `super(props)`, (2) initialises state and (3) binds functions.

3. Your later part is on the point.
4. > bindwill create a new function that is bounded well with the object,
   >   making sure when the function is called, it will be direct to the
   >   right object because for some reason if I don't bind it, my button
   >   will be like 'button onClick={undefined.doNothing}>, because of some
   >   class rule

`this` in React component refers to the component itself. Functions provided by React.Component, e.g. `render` always have `this` binding to the component, while your own defined functions don't. So `<button onClick={this.doNothing}>` in `render()` will not pose any issue, but `doNothing()` needs to be bound in constructor to get access to `this`.

> The meaning of arguments I passed, I have seen some example but they
>   didn't really pass any argument. (The props constructor(props)
>   super(props))

Look up to point 1. If you use `super()` instead of `super(props)`, `this.props` will be undefined inside constructor. It is still accessible in other functions.
[Here is the original answer to this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34995257/2404452)

> The whole bind code looks odd to me, this.doNothing is changed into
>   what? this.this.doNothing? How does it really works, why my button
>   knows where to find it?

Look up to point 4. `this.doNothing().bind(this)` allows you to access `this` inside function `doNothing()`, including reading state, props and calling other functions of the component. Without binding, `this` will be undefined inside `doNothing()`.

Comment: Thank you! this is super helpful! I will have to take some time process them all but I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

When you define a variable using the `this` keyword, it belongs to the scope of the React class and hence can you used throughout the scope of the React class.

> The meaning of arguments I passed, I have seen some example but they
>   didn't really pass any argument.

As far as bind is concerned, `.bind` takes the context as an argument and returns a function, which when executed will refer to the context of the React class. The rest of the arguments that are passed to bind are made available to the function when it is called.

For example when you write

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);  
    this.doNothing = this.doNothing.bind(this);
  }
```

The function that is returned by bind is assigned to a variable `doNothing` which is defined in the class scope. If you change it to

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);  
    this.someNewFunction = this.doNothing.bind(this);
}
```

you will use it like

```
render(){
    <button onClick={this.someNewFunction}>I do nothing xD</button>
  }
```

Comment: ohh! `this.doNothing` isn't the function itself, it is just a variable, in `this.doNothing.bind(this)`, `this.doNothing` is actually the function and it is bounded to the object saved into the variable `this.doNothing`, that's how it is bind?

Comment: @DonghuiMa, you should look into the documentation of bind to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You already set `props` yourself without knowing:

```
 <button onClick={this.doNothing}>
```

Here `onClick` will be set to `this.doNothing` inside of the `props` passed to the `button` constructor. To pass props to your `Example` class one can do:

```
 <Example color="blue" />
```

Now in the `render` method for example you can access it as:

```
 <button style = {{ color: this.props.color }} > Some button </button>
```

Through that your components can be reused at different places, as the parent can change their props to define their behaviour.

Comment: hmm It is helpful for sure, now I know I can set props in component's own render function. but I mainly don't understand why I need to write `props`, like `super(props)` and `constructor(props)`

Comment: @donghui otherwise they would get lost and wouldnt appear at `this.props`