# What is the reason for passing props to super() in a React constructor when props aren't accessed within it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I've seen many code snippets such as `HelloWorld`, where `props` is passed to `super()`. 
What is the reason to do that when `this.props` **is not accessed** in the constructor?

```
class HelloWorld extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { message: 'Hi' };
        this.logMessage = this.logMessage.bind(this);
    }

    logMessage() {
        console.log(this.state.message);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input type="button" value="Log" onClick={this.logMessage} />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason really. If you're not using `this.props` in the constructor, all you need to do is call `super()`. The `Component` superclass will setup props just fine, they just won't be accessible inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The *constructor* for a React component is called before it is mounted. When implementing the constructor for a React component subclass, you should call `super(props)` before any other statement. 
**Otherwise, `this.props` will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to bugs**.

Read [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to use `this.props` in your constructor, you don't have to put it into `super()` like this:

```
constructor(){
   super();
   this.state = { randomState: "" };
   this.randomProperty = null;
}
```

But, in some cases, `props` passed from the parent component can be accessed and used inside constructor for initializing state (these props are not affected by prop change). By passing `props` to `super`, you can now use `this.props` inside constructor.

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = { randomVar: props.initialValue, propDependentState: this.props.someValue };
   this.someVar = props.defaultValue;
   this.anotherVar = this.props.openToChangesProp;
}
```

Take note that those `props` that are directly passed to this component are the only props accessible to the constructor. `props` that are mapped from state using redux `connect` is included in the props that can't be accessed here since the component hasn't mounted yet.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do `super(props)`. That is done only to access `props` inside the constructor. You can write:

```
constructor(){
 super()
 this.state={}
}
```

If you do not pass `super(props)`:

```
 constructor(props){
  super()
  console.log('this.props', this.props); // => undefined
  console.log('props', props); // => whatever the props is
 }
```

Refer [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571875/whats-the-difference-between-super-and-superprops-in-react-when-using-e)