# Why are my props not being passed to my child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to create a modal in React that displays some information when a `button` in `App.js` is clicked.

When I put the modal code in `App.js`, it successfully populated the data (albeit for every li at once).

I moved the modal to it's own component, but I'm getting `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

Here's my App.js code:

```
const APIURL = 'https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries?';
const citySearch = 'by_city=boston';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      breweries: [],
      show: false
    };
  }

  handleClose() {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  }

  handleShow() {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(APIURL + citySearch)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            breweries: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, breweries } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
        {breweries.map(brewery => (
          <div className="brewery-card">
          <li key={brewery.id}>
          <p id="brewery-name">{brewery.name}</p>
          <p id="brewery-type">{brewery.brewery_type}</p> 
          <p id="brewery-address">{brewery.street} {brewery.city}, {brewery.state} {breweries.postal_code} </p>
          <button onClick={this.handleShow}>Details</button>
          <a href={brewery.website_url} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Visit Site</a>
          </li>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <DetailsModal props={this.props.brewery} show={this.state.modalShow} />
      </div>
     );
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

And here's my component code, which isn't receiving props:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

class DetailsModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            show: false
        };
    }
    render() {

        const brewery = this.props.brewery;

        return (
            <Modal {...this.props}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title>{brewery.name}</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>{brewery.street} {brewery.city}, {brewery.state} {brewery.postal_code}</Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
                Close
              </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>
        )
    }
}

  export default DetailsModal;
```

What am I missing that is preventing props from `App.js` from being used in `DetailsModal.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing props with the wrong name (or accessing it wrong)

This

```
<DetailsModal props={this.props.brewery} show={this.state.modalShow} />
```

Should be

```
//              \/ here
<DetailsModal brewery={this.props.brewery} show={this.state.modalShow} />
```

When you do `const brewery = this.props.brewery;` you are trying to access `brewery` from props but you didn't provided `brewery` in the props, only `props` and `show`.

Here is an example to clarify what is happening.

Here you are passing `someProp` to `ComponentX`

Inside `ComponentX` `this.props` will be an object with the passed props, and in this case, it will be

```
{
    someProp: "something"
}
```

So `this.props.someProp` return `"something"`

If you try to access `this.props.someOtherProp` it will return `undefined`.
And if you try to access `this.props.someOtherProp.X` you will get an error of `annot read property 'X' of undefined`

If you are having problems to understand how props works, please look at the [examples](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component) from the docs.

## Edit:

The other reason why you are getting the error is that in `App` `this.props.brewery` doesn't exist.

Only thing related to `brewery` or `breweries` is in your state.

So that is another error. And you need to specify what you want to display in `DetailsModal`

## Edit 2:

To display the brewery when you click it, you need to keep in the state the value of the clicked brewery and pass that to the modal

1. Add to the `App` state `currentBrewery`

   ```
   this.state = {
       error: null,
       isLoaded: false,
       breweries: [],
       show: false,
       currentBrewery: {}
   };
   ```
2. Add to the `onClick` to set `currentBrewery` as the `brewery` from the `breweries`

   ```
   <button onClick={() => this.handleShow(brewery)}>Details</button>
   ```

   And

   ```
   handleShow(brewery) {
       this.setState({ show: true, currentBrewery: brewery });
   }
   ```
3. Give `DetailsModal` the `currentBrewery` that is in your state

   ```
   <DetailsModal brewery={this.state.currentBrewery} show={this.state.modalShow} />
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still getting `can't read property 'name' of undefined` though, I'm reading the docs now, but I'm guessing the error now lies in my `DetailsModal.js`?

Comment: `this.state.breweries` is an array. You want display only the clicked brewery  ? I know how to solve the problem, but don't know what is the result you want

Comment: `DetailsModal` for each individual brewery. Thanks!

Comment: I thought that `constructor(props) super(props)` made `this.props.brewery` valid? I'm not sure what goes on under the hood there and will look it up.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34995257/9119186) will help you

Comment: You want to display the modal only when you click at an brewery?

Comment: Yes, there's a `details` button that's generated for each brewery, and I'd like to set it up so that once its clicked, the modal appears.

Comment: @James I think now it's working for you, just edited

Comment: Thanks @Vencovsky, while the page is loading now, the modal doesn't actually show. I'm looking to see if there's a mismatch in method calls or something

Comment: Change `show={this.state.showModal}` to `show={this.state.show}`

Comment: Thank you very much. The modal isn't overlaying as it should, but that'll be another post if I can't figure it out