# Not showing image upload field in react

Tags: reactjs

i need to create image upload field it is easy but it is not working.my code is below.i am working on the part of big project.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';



export default class commonFormModel extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super();
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="file" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit"/>
            </div>                                    
            );
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it is not working" part? Also, component name has to start with a capital letter

Comment: above code show the button but not show the image upload field what is the reason for

Comment: The code in question is obviously [working](https://codesandbox.io/s/6v2jyk6pxn), please create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you still have issues

Comment: Code is seems to be working dude. Which browser you are working? Check your console for any error or warning.

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing this component to another component, you must have getting this warning,

```
Warning: <commonFormModel /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
```

In JSX, lower-case tag names are considered to be HTML tags. However, lower-case tag names with a dot (property accessor) aren't.

- `<component />` compiles to `React.createElement('component')` (html tag)
- `<Component />` compiles to `React.createElement(Component)` (react component)
- `<obj.component />` compiles to `React.createElement(obj.component)` (react component)

You must change classname to `PascalCase`

```
export default class commonFormModel extends Component { //Incorrect way

export default class CommonFormModel extends Component { //Correct way
```

And finally you can use your component like,

```
<CommonFormModel />
```

**Note:** If you don't have `state` for your component, I suggest you to go for [`functional component`](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). If you think in future you may have `state` to this component, then you can use a `constructor`, but make sure while calling `super()`, you should pass your `props` to it like `super(props)`, in your case you are missing that. Also see [difference between `super()` & `super(this)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571875/whats-the-difference-between-super-and-superprops-in-react-when-using-e).

Comment: thank you for ur answer,i get more knowledge from this.

Comment: i solved it,that field hidden by the css properties