# React redux won't update class component's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component which is supposed to update if a state from another component has been changed using redux, but it's not.

Inside `mapStateToProps` the correct value is being returned on redux action.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import './DashboardContent.scss';
import * as entries from '../../../assets/demo.json';

import CategoryHeader from "./CategoryHeader/CategoryHeader";
import NoContent from "../../../shared/NoContent/NoContent";
import UnsortedList from "./UnsortedList/UnsortedList";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

class DashboardContent extends Component {

    state = {
        activeCategory: this.props.activeCategory
    };

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        console.log(this.props.activeCategory)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               ...
            </div>
        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log(state);
    return {
        activeCategory: state.category
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DashboardContent);
```

Dispatch inside of another component - when this is being executed, the state `activeCategory` of first component shall become `some value`:

```
dispatch(changeCategory('some value'))
```

Actions.js

```
// Action types
const CHANGE_CATEGORY = 'CHANGE_CATEGORY'


// Action creators
export const changeCategory = (category) => {
    return {
        type: CHANGE_CATEGORY,
        category
    }
}
```

Reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  activeCategory: 'all'
};

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log('reducer', state, action);
    if (action.type === 'CHANGE_CATEGORY') {
        return action.category
    }
    return state;
};
```

Comment: does the `console.log` in `componentDidUpdate` show the new value?

Comment: What happens when you add this to the main class:(class DashboardContent extends Component) {
  constructor() {
  super();
  this.props = 0;
 }

Comment: Currently you only set initial value of state to `props.activeCategory`. Use the `componentDidUpdate` to check for new props and update the state there, or use `getDerivedStateFromProps` instead, with the same purpose.

Comment: @pawel No unfortunately not.

Comment: @kbo `componentDidUpdate` won't run when the redux state is being updated.

Comment: I would try `getDerivedStateFromProps` then, since it fires on every prop change.

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer should return the updated state instead it returns action.category atm.

```
export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log('reducer', state, action);
  if (action.type === 'CHANGE_CATEGORY') {
   return {...state,category:action.category}; 
  }
  return state;
};
```

Comment: This returns an object inside of `mapStateToProps`, which is good, but I'm smh still not able to access it from inside of the component.

Comment: Does the console.log(state) in mapStateToProps show the updated category in the state. If so you should be able to access it with this.props.activeCategory.

Comment: Yes it does but I'm not able to access it, it's odd. `const store = createStore(reducer)` - that's how I initialized it using the `Provider` from `react-redux`

Comment: Then what do you mean by saying you are not able to access it inside of component. What does console.log(this.props.activeCategory) inside of componentDidUpdate logs?

Comment: Nothing - componentDidUpdate won't even run and rendering `this.props.activeCategory` whatsoever inside of JSX won't print anything either.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you add this to the main class?(class DashboardContent extends Component)
I believe you need to do that when you try to access the  this.props.activeCategory. Try to add this snippet.

```
 constructor(props) { 
 super(props); 
 this.state = this.props.activeCategory;
 }
```

You may refer to this answer:[What's the difference between "super()" and "super(props)" in React when using es6 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571875/whats-the-difference-between-super-and-superprops-in-react-when-using-e)

Comment: I'm somehow still not able to get the data from redux to my component.

Comment: How are you rendering it in the code? Can you paste here the JSX.

Answer (score 0):

when you are connecting a component to redux, the second argument is the dispatchToProps, is the only way you can dispatch an action inside your component

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {action1, action2,})(DashboardContent);
```